# Реализация "заглушек" Mock в JavaScript с помощу SinonJS

Tags: javascript, mocking, sinonjs

Мне нужно протестировать работу сервера, но на локальной машине функционал отправки писем не работает, поэтому для отправки писем нужно сделать заглушку с помощью SinonJS.

Проблема в том, что я впервые столкнулся с такой задачей и с тестированием. Принципиально что к чему я разобрался, а вот когда доходит до реализации проблемы, никак не могу понять где именно надо создавать мок и как именно его создавать.

Может у кого-то есть наглядные примеры кода или кто-то может мне показать, как именно это делать?

Вот функция, которую нужно замокать, она должна отправлять письмо для активизации учетной записи, но на локальной машине это не нужно настраивать, просто нужно как-то сделать заглушку.

```
var originalFunction = function(event){
  return Bb
      .try(() => {
        let templateData = {
          appName: config.app.title,
          name: event.user.name,
          token: event.user.emailVerificationToken
        };
        return verificationTpl(templateData);
      })
      .then(function (emailHtml) {
        var mailOptions = _.extend({
          to: event.user.username,
          html: emailHtml
        }, verificationEmailOptions, emailConfig.options);

        log.info('Sending mail to: ' + mailOptions.to);

        var retValue = emailConfig.transport.sendMailAsync(mailOptions);
        return retValue;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        log.error('Cannot send mail: ' + err);
      });
};
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос описание конкретного объекта, который вы хотите мокать. Без этой конкретики, можно посоветовать только читать документацию, т.к. вопрос слишком общий

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В текущем виде вы можете правильно протестировать всего один факт: функция `originalFunction` вызывается с правильными параметрами. А сделать это можно так:

```
let sinon = require('sinon'),
    should = require('should'),
    stub = sinon.stub();

// Заглушка всегда будет возвращать выполненное обещание.
stub.returns(Promise.resolve());

// Передавайте заглушку вашему модулю, и выполняйте над ним действия, приводящие
// к отправке почты. По завершению этих действий, выполните проверку
// аргументов. Не забудьте об АСИНХРОННОСТИ.

// Пример тестируемого модуля.
let m = new Module(stub);

m.doSomething().then(() => {
    // Функция должна быть вызвана...
    stub.calledOnce.should.be.true();
    // ... с правильным аргументом.
    let firstCall = stub.getCall(0);
    firstCall.arg.should.be.eql({
        user: {
            name: 'foo',
            emailVerificationToken: 'bar'
        }
    });
});
```

**Замечание:**

Да, при желании можно мокать и глобальные переменные `log`, `config`, `emailConfig` и прочие, но это путь в никуда. Вместо нормальных модульных тестов, у вас получится набор невнятного кода, сильно сцепленный с реализацией `originalFunction`. А чтобы сделать действительно *модульные тесты* вам нужно выкинуть все глобальные переменные и передавать зависимости явно.

Comment: Спасибо за пример, но заглушку надо сделать не для входящих даних етой функции, а скорее вместо функции, так как отправка письма приводит к ошибкам на етой машине, мне просто нужно сделать так чтоби из функции возвращались значения удачного виполнения несмотря на то, что случитса внутри

Comment: @pj-infest, Ну так а кто мешает вам возвращать все, что вы хотите в `stub.returns`? Вы поймите, что если речь идет о _тестах_, то все, что вы можете протестировать -- это правильные аргументы. А если вам просто нужна _заглушка_, то вам хватит простой анонимной функции вида `() => Promise.resolve({field: 'data'})`. Sinon здесь не нужен